# Как прочитать из application.yml число типа Long

Tags: java, spring

в файле application.yml имеется настройка типа Long:

```
producer.init-delay: 15000
```

Она используется в этом методе:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 25000, initialDelay = "#{new Long('${producer.init-delay}')}")
public produce() {}
```

Пример взять из вопроса :[Spring @Value TypeMismatchException:...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733067/spring-value-typemismatchexceptionfailed-to-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-s/42735568#42735568)
Но у меня это код выдает ошибку:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'long'
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `initialDelay` используйте [initialDelayString](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#initialDelayString--)

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 25000, initialDelayString = "${producer.init-delay}")
public produce() {}
```

Ответ нашёл тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598712/how-to-parameterize-scheduledfixeddelay-with-spring-3-0-expression-language